# Pyspark dataframe replace \"" from column vaues

Tags: pyspark

I am loading a csv file into a data frame. I have tried the below code to replace the occurrences of **""** in the column named description but it doesn't replace them.

```
df = df.withColumn('Description',F.regexp_replace('Description','\""', ""))
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks